# Can I ask questions about organizing a brew competition?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm planning on organizing a small brewing competition sometime in the next 12 months. I'd like to leverage other people's knowledge on this.

Can I ask this sort of question on the main homebrewing site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure others disagree with me, but people have asked questions on ideas for club meetings, breweries to visit, and the interest in having homegrown hops tested, so I don't see why not.

Comment: thx for your support, I'll wait a bit and see what others think

Comment: It seems to me that if it promotes homebrewing, it should be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

That seems like a perfectly generalizable class of question that would be helpful to others -- "how do I organize a brewing competition?" so I say go for it.

Comment: I'd have to agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that such a question promotes home brewing and is relevant. But I know that there are the purists that flag anything that is not procedure oriented. I'd say let the competition question in, if the purpose of this site is to promote home brewing.